# "Pate" für "Patenkind"

Tags: meaning, dialect

Laut Duden kann *Pate* nicht nur für den Zeugen, sondern auch für das *Patenkind* stehen ([Link](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pate_Taufpate_Patron_Patenonkel)). Mir (aufgewachsen an Orten, wo schwäbische und ostfränkische Dialekte gesprochen wurden) erscheint das ganz normal, aber der Duden bezeichnet diesen Gebrauch als *landschaftlich, sonst veraltet*.

Ist die Einschätzung des Duden korrekt? Wird *Pate* nur in gewissen Regionen für *Patenkind* gebraucht? Wenn ja, in welchen?

Comment: _"Mir erscheint das ganz normal"_ Heißt das, Du kennst die Verwendung von "Pate" für "Patenkind"? Könntest Du dann bitte Deinen eigenen sprachlichen Hintergrund  (bzw. den Deiner Familie) ergänzen?

Comment: Ich benutze es selber so, was aber nicht heißen muß, daß es in der Region, aus der ich stamme, üblich ist.

Comment: Wirst Du denn in Deiner Region oder in Deiner Familie (die ja aus einer anderen Region stammen mag) _verstanden_, wenn Du das so benutzt? Oder kommt es zu Rückfragen und/oder Missverständnissen?

Comment: Das weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Mir sind die Begriffe "Patenonkel", "Patentante" und "Patenkind" ein Begriff. Dass "Pate" auch als Kurzform und/oder geschlechtsneutrale Version von Patenonkel/-tante benutzt wird (obwohl ich andererseits auch schon die weibliche Form "Patin" gehört habe...), ist mir durchaus bewusst, obwohl bei "Pate" für mich immer die Assoziation Mafia zumindest unterschwellig mitschwingt. Pate als Kurzform für Patenkind habe ich hingegen noch nie gehört und halte das infolge der Mehrdeutigkeit und Verwechslungsgefahr für reichlich fragwürdig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In seinem Aufsatz "Die deutschen Verwandtschaftsnamen" (*Zeitschrift für hochdeutsche Mundarten*, 1900, [Link](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_T5FkCYw9U10C/page/n209)) prägt Wilhelm Schoof den Begriff der "Rückgabe der Anrede".

> Die Gemütlichkeit altgermanischen Familienlebens brachte es vielfach mit sich, daß ein dem Alter und dem Range nach übergeordneter Verwandter mit einem jüngeren Freundschafts- und Namenstausch einging. (S. 259)

Als Beispiele führt er an:

- *Neffe* kann im Mhd. (entgegen dem heutigen Gebrauch) sowohl das Bruder- oder Schwesterkind als auch den Oheim bezeichnen (S. 260). ([DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=neffe))
- In Schweizerdeutschen kann *Äni* den Großvater, aber auch den Enkel bezeichnen (S. 263 f.). ([Idiotikon](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id1.htm#!page/10247/mode/1up))
- Im Westfälischen ist *Nichte* Geschwisterstochter, Tante (S. 267). ([DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=nichte) hat mittelrhein. *nyecht* mutterschwester)
- Schließlich *Pate* als Bezeichnung des Patenkindes (S. 286). Das DWB führt diese Bedeutung, wie von tofro zitiert, für nhd. [*Pate*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=pate) auf, aber auch unter dem Lemma [*Pfetter*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=pfetter) für das Mnl. ([Middelnederlandsch Woordenboek](http://gtb.ivdnt.org/iWDB/search?actie=article&wdb=MNW&id=42509&lemmodern=peter&domein=0&conc=true))

Man gewinnt den Eindruck, daß diese "Rückgabe" etwas äußerst Natürliches ist, dem vielleicht erst das zunehmende Bedürfnis nach Genauigkeit des Ausdrucks den Garaus gemacht hat.

Answer (score 4):

Auf der [Wikipedia-Seite zum Begriff *Pate*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pate#Dialektale,_altert%C3%BCmliche_und_sonstige_Bezeichnungen) gibt es eine Liste regionaler Bezeichnungen für *Pate/Patin* und *Patenkind*. *Pate* als Alternative für *Patenkind* ist dort aber nicht aufgeführt. Die alternative Verwendung von *Pate* für *Patenkind* habe ich noch nie gehört. 
Einen Hinweis findet man beim [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pate). Hier wird als Quelle *WDG, 1974* genannt; also das in der DDR aufgelegte [*Wörterbuch der Deutschen Gegenwartssprache*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_deutschen_Gegenwartssprache). Möglicherweise ist das ein Hinweis auf eine frühere regionale Verwendung im ostdeutschen Raum aber das ist leider nur eine Mutmaßung.

Comment: ...oder die Quelle von 1974 ist ein Hinweis auf den _veralteten_ Gebrauch.

Comment: Wobei das WDG die Bedeutung nicht als veraltet oder regional kennzeichnet: https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Pate

Answer (score 4):

Grimm's Wörterbuch weiß das  durchaus auch und zitiert auch den Meister selbst mit diesen Worten:

> 2) nhd. auch täufling in beziehung auf den taufpaten, das patenkind: dem pathen etwas spendieren. rockenphilos. 416 (3, 48); was macht mein pathe (Friedr. König)? Lessing 12, 250, vergl. 382; wir nehmen herzlichen antheil an dem guten fortgang meines kleinen pathens. Wieland an Merck 2, 131; als ältester enkel und pathe hatte ich .. jeden sonntag bei den groszeltern gespeist. Göthe 24, 71.

Anscheinend scheint (schien?) das akzeptiert, wenn aus dem Zusammenhang heraus klar wird, dass es sich um ein Kind, damit also nur um ein Patenkind, handelt.

In meinem eigenen (schwäbischen) Dialekt ist das durchaus auch so möglich.

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn mir der Begriff des Paten im Sinne von Patenkind ebenfalls noch nie untergekommen ist denke ich, dass der Begriff eine Abschleifung des Begriffs

> Patchen

ist, was nichts anderes als ein Patenkind ist. Evtl. auch um ein älteres Patenkind zu kennzeichnen, das nicht mehr "chen" ist.

Siehe Eintrag Patchen bei [dwds/wdg-3](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Pate), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Patchen)

Comment: Aber woher kommt dann *Patchen*?

Comment: @DavidVogt Wilde Spekulation: Sieht man das als Diminutiv ist der Unterschied zwischen Patenkind und Patchen nicht so groß. Getauft wird ja normalerweise im Babyalter. Das Baby dann als Patchen, statt als Patenkind zu bezeichnen sehe ich im Bereich des Möglichen.

Comment: Aber normalerweise kann ich *Kind* doch nicht durch *chen* ersetzen (*Sorgenchen, Findelchen*)?